# Firestore Node.js .orderBy timestamp returning empty result

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Node.js Firestore query that I'm calling `.onSnapshot` on and it's returning an empty result:

```
const query = firebase.firestore()
    .collection("stuff")
    .orderBy("created_at", "desc")
    .where("owner_id", "==", id)
    .onSnapshot(
      { includeMetadataChanges: false },
      (querySnap: QuerySnap) => {
        subs.next(querySnap.docs)
      },
      (error: Error) => subs.error(error),
      () => subs.complete()
    );
```

### ***`created_at` is a timestamp and `owner_id` is a string for each document; and I can confirm that both exist and aren't `null` for any of the entries.***

Is there something wrong with how I'm using `.orderBy` here, or what are some other causes for this issue?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Can you try with orderby keyword follwed by where.!?

Comment: @pepe tried it and also didn’t work

Comment: Does the document have the fields owner_id as well as the created_at,and attach a get method with the code

Comment: Yes, please check my question I specified that

Comment: It is very hard to say without having more codes,kindly share your code

Comment: Will do, I’ll post more code in the next few hours, thanks!

Comment: did you logged the value id which one you are passing..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out I didn't have the indexing set up in the Firebase console. I've used it before with Realtime Database but didn't realize you needed them with Firestore as well.

Comment: Hey, do not forget to accept your own answer after [48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so it gains more relevance and other people with the same problem can find this solution easily.